# What happens if you enter a Recursion via the Strange?

Tags: the-strange

I understand that, if you just cross a gate from a Recursion to another (or from / to a Primary World like Earth) you can do this normally via an inapposite gate, but you risk dying if the laws are incompatible (like going from earth to Ruk).

But, if you go from a Recursion to another (or Primary World) by traveling the Strange, does this also happen? Or can you arrive at the other Recursion as you just got through sea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entering a recursion from The Strange incurs the same problems as entering it via *inapposite gate* from another recursion or from Earth.  However, the risk of death is not immediate - it takes some time for your PC's body to break down in the new environment.  (And, as you noted, this is not the case if the Laws of the target recursion are compatible with the Laws of the origination.)  Travelers to The Strange carry around themselves a thin film of their previous recursion, which protects them from the "environment" of the Chaosphere.  (See sidebar, p228 of *The Strange* core rulebook.)

From *The Strange* (core rulebook), p135:

> **Creatures and PCs:** Just like objects, creatures can pass through an inapposite gate (whether conscious or not) without being translated to suit the target recursion. Like complex objects of any sort, creatures that operate under a different law who pass through an inapposite gate begin to lose their special abilities over a number of days equal to 1d6 × the creature’s level (or tier, if they’re PCs). If a creature’s life force is particularly tied to an unsupported law, it dies at the end of that time (but most creatures survive, despite being debilitated and in pain; treat them as if one step down on the damage track). Before a creature loses its unsupported special abilities completely, all uses of that ability are modified by one step to its detriment until the creature finally loses the ability or dies, or until it returns to its native recursion (at which point it begins to recover).

For instance, if a level 3 skeleton of Ardeyn appears on Earth through an inapposite gate, it “survives” on Earth for 1d6 × 3 days (because its special ability is its animation). Given that any physical action a skeleton takes relies on its magical animation, a skeleton’s attacks are hindered by Earth’s law of Standard Physics while it persists.

From *The Strange* (core rulebook), p212:

> **Connection to Recursions:** Various recursions allow access to and from the Strange. For example, Ardeyn residents can travel directly into (or fall into) the Strange from the edge of the recursion. Entering a recursion from the Strange is like entering the recursion through an inapposite gate.